# Getting an object out of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (student objects which have properties like `studentID`, `grade`, `dob`, `registeredDate`) and I have another array of objects (books objects which have properties `studentID`, `bookID`, `bookISBN`).

It's a Web app for managing the library at a small school. What I want to do is that when a book (say has title *Welcome Home*) has been borrowed by student with `studentID` 4, when you try to lend that book (of course a copy since the library can have a number of them in stock) to someone else, the student with `studentID` 4 shouldn't be available in the list of students who are eligible to get that book (unless if the student had returned the book first).

The booksList Array is like below:

```
[
{
bookEdition: "2nd edition",
bookISBN: 9876533278765,
bookStatus: 0,
bookTitle: "Real Machines",
dateTaken: "2018-10-28",
returnDate: "2018-11-27",
studentID: "0000003"
},

{
bookEdition: "2015 edition",
bookISBN: 9876532226712,
bookStatus: 0,
bookTitle: "Real Machines",
dateTaken: "2018-08-28",
returnDate: "2018-09-27",
studentID: "0000004"
}
];
```

The studentsList is as below:

```
[
{
bio: "Needs extra work. Has problems with mathematics",
birthday: "2005-05-12",
className: "grade 5",
fullname: "Bridget Friday",
gender: "Female",
parentName: "Josam Friday",
studentID: "0000003",
studentStatus: "approved"
}, 

{
bio: "A bit naughty but intelligent. Pay close attention to his diet.",
birthday: "2003-11-07",
className: "grade 6",
fullname: "Charles Ben",
gender: "Male",
parentName: "Chris Ben",
studentID: "0000004",
studentStatus: "approved"
}
];
```

Now, I was trying to use the filter function but it doesn't give me the results I want. The thing that links the two array objects and the objects in them is the `studentID`.

I tried

```
var legitStudents = studentsList.filter(el => {
  return !booksList.includes(el.studentID);
});
```

The above doesn't work. The arrays (`studentList` and `booksList`) are fetched dynamically and I can't tell which `studentID`s are in `booksList`.

How can I get this to work as I want them?

Comment: We can't help without knowing what the format of `studentsList` and `booksList` is. I'd tend to assume `booksList` isn't an array of student IDs, which is what your code expects it to be. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: `!booksList.includes(el.studentID);` this isn't right since `booksList` is not an array of `studentIDs`. It's an array objects

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right now I can't put it here, I'm using Angular 6 and it's just a bit complex for me right now. I'll just log the studentList array and the booksList array so you can see what they contain.

Comment: @SajalPreetSingh I understand that. So what could be the best way to go about it?

Comment: @Kingsley - It's better to ask a properly-formed question. If you can't do that right now, I suggest deleting the question and posting it when you can.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added the booksList array. The studentsList array has a similar format except that it has different data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return !booksList.includes(el.studentID);
```

should be

```
return !booksList.map(i => i.studentID).includes(el.studentID);
```

As a couple people said in the comments of your question, the problem is your code is expecting `booksList` to be an array of `studentID`s. Since it's actually a list of books that have been checked out by students, you first need to make an array of all `studentID`s in `booksList` then you can use `includes` on the resulting array. See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: This also works and it's pretty clear to understand. Big thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rocky Sims' solution or you can try this as well

```
var legitStudents = studentList.filter(student => {
  return !booksList.filter(book => book.studentID === student.studentID).length;
});
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm. I just don't understand why there should be length at the end. If I take it out it doesn't work. Big thanks, though. It just works out fine...

Comment: `booksList.filter(book => book.studentID === student.studentID)` gives out an array of either length 1 or 0. So `!` and `.length` to get the necessary boolean